# Apply negative lookbehind to the entire group before it

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture the model of a phone but not the storage in the title. So I don't want the regex to match `xxxGB`.

I am expecting to match:

**iphone 13** from: "**iphone 13 256gb - midnight**"

**iphone 13 pro max** from "**iphone 13 pro max 256gb - sierra blue**"

**iphone 13 pro** from "**iphone 13 pro 128gb - graphite**"

**galaxy tab a8** from "**galaxy tab a8 wifi 128gb - grey**"

The regular expression I have is

```
r'[A-Za-z]+\s?[A-Za-z\+\.\d]*((\spro|\smax|\slight|\smini|\splus|\sultra|\[A-Za-z]?\d+(?!gb)))*|$'
```

but the look behind only applied to the last number before "gb" not the entire number after the space

```
apple iphone 13 256gb - midnight
<re.Match object; span=(6, 18), match='iphone 13 25'>
<re.Match object; span=(32, 32), match=''>
apple iphone 13 pro 128gb - graphite
<re.Match object; span=(6, 22), match='iphone 13 pro 12'>
<re.Match object; span=(36, 36), match=''>
apple iphone 13 pro max 256gb - sierra blue
<re.Match object; span=(6, 26), match='iphone 13 pro max 25'>
<re.Match object; span=(43, 43), match=''>
samsung galaxy tab a8 wifi 128gb - grey
<re.Match object; span=(8, 21), match='galaxy tab a8'>
<re.Match object; span=(39, 39), match=''>
```

The testing template can be found from here: https://regex101.com/r/dn0Hyr/1

Many thanks!!

Comment: How are we to know why the Android phone is a`'galaxy tab a8'` rather than a `'galaxy tab a8 wifi'` considering that one of the iPhones is a `'iphone 13 pro'`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to match phone models:

```py
^[A-Za-z]+(?: (?!wifi|\d*gb)[\dA-Za-z]+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dn0Hyr/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[A-Za-z]+`: Match 1+ letters
- `(?: (?!wifi|\d*gb)[\dA-Za-z]+)*`: Delimited by space match 1+ of letters or digits as long as word is not `wifi` or digits followed by `gb`. Repeat this group 0 or more times

Answer (score 1):

An alternative between two positive look ahead:

**Figure I - Regex A**

```
/^.*(?=\swifi\s\d{3})|^.*(?=\s\d{3})/gm
```

[RegEx A at RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/B85eif/1)

**Figure II - RegEx A**

| Segment | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `^.*` | Starting with anything **BUT** a newline occurring zero or more times... |
| `(?=\swifi\s\d{3})` | ...is a match if it is before a space, literal "wifi", a space, and 3 digits... |
| `|` | OR |
| `^.*` | ...starting with anything **BUT** a newline occurring zero or more times... |
| `(?=\s\d{3})` | ...is a match if it is before a space and 3 digits. |

or a shortened version without the alternative and matches 2 and 3 digits as per The fourth bird's comment below. Note, rather than an alternative, a non-capturing group `(?:wifi\s)?` is nested inside the look ahead and the quantifier `?` doesn't make the match a requirement just a possibility:

**Figure III - RegEx B**

```
/^.*?(?=\s(?:wifi\s)?\d{2,3}gb)/gm
```

[Regex B at RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/GcsOvD/1)

**Figure IV - RegEx B**

| Segment | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `^.*?` | Starting with anything BUT a newline occurring zero or more times until... |
| `(?=\s(?:wifi\s)?`... | ...there's a space, literal "wifi", and a space occurring once or not at all... |
| ...`\d{2,3}gb)` | ...followed by 2 or 3 digits, and literal "gb" |

Comment: You might shorten the pattern to `^.*?(?=\s(?:wifi\s)?\d{3})` but note that matching 3 digits will exclude matching  `galaxy tab a8 wifi 64gb` although we don't really know what the OP wants to match out of a lot of different phone models.

Comment: Thanks, updated to include `{2,3}` as well. Lately I've been using `|` trying to use this [trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) but it morphs into something else.